# android Layout length not getting completely stretched by height

Tags: android, android-layout

I have following XML layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="@android:color/white" >
        <LinearLayout 
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/CanLogoImageView"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:layout_margin="30dp"
                android:src="@drawable/can__logo" />

                <LinearLayout android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
                          android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
                          android:orientation="vertical" >

                          <RelativeLayout android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                                            android:layout_height="fill_parent">

                                         <EditText android:id="@+id/emailEditText"
                                                    android:layout_width="300dp"
                                                    android:layout_height="50dp"
                                                    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                                                    android:hint="@string/email_hint"
                                                    android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
                                                    android:textColor="@color/black" />

                                          <EditText android:id="@+id/passwordEditText"
                                                    android:layout_width="300dp"
                                                    android:layout_height="50dp"
                                                    android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
                                                    android:layout_below="@+id/emailEditText"
                                                    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                                                    android:hint="@string/password_hint"
                                                    android:inputType="textPassword"
                                                    android:textColor="@color/black" />

                                          <Button android:id="@+id/loginButton"
                                                    android:layout_width="300dp"
                                                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                                    android:layout_below="@+id/passwordEditText"
                                                    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                                                    android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
                                                    android:text="@string/login_button_text" />

                                          <!-- Forgot Password? TextView -->
                                          <TextView android:id="@+id/forgot_password_textView"
                                                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                                    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                                                    android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
                                                    android:gravity="center"
                                                    android:layout_below="@+id/loginButton"
                                                    android:text="@string/forgot_password_textview"
                                                    android:textColor="@color/blue"  />

                                          <!-- My payment methods test textView  - TO BE REMOVED LATER! USED THIS FOR TESTING -->
                                          <!--  <TextView android:id="@+id/paymentmethodstest_textView"
                                                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                                    android:text="@string/payment_methods_test_textView"
                                                    android:layout_below="@+id/loginButton"
                                                    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                                                    android:layout_marginLeft="40dp"
                                                    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/forgot_password_textView"
                                                    android:textStyle="bold"
                                                    android:textColor="@color/red"/>    -->

                                          <!-- Don't have an account TextView -->
                                          <TextView android:id="@+id/dontHaveAccountTextView"
                                                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                                    android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
                                                    android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
                                                    android:layout_below= "@+id/forgot_password_textView"
                                                    android:text="@string/donthave_account_textview"
                                                    android:textColor="@color/black" />

                                          <!-- Sign up now TextView -->
                                          <TextView android:id="@+id/signup_now_textView"
                                                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                                    android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
                                                    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/dontHaveAccountTextView"
                                                    android:layout_below= "@+id/forgot_password_textView"
                                                    android:text="@string/signup_now_textview"
                                                    android:textColor="@color/blue" />

                            </RelativeLayout>
</LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

The screen is displayed as below.

[image]

The screen is not getting stretched completely lengthwise. As you can see, there is black patch at the bottom of the screen shot.

**Can anyone let me know where I'm going wrong?**

Answer (score 0):

the first linear layout doesn't have a height of "match_parent" .

it depends on the children of it .

Answer (score 0):

Should be:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="@android:color/white" >
```

And remove ScrollView

Comment: I used scrollview because I want the user be able to scroll up and down through the screen when the keyboard appears on screen.

Answer (score 0):

Add `android:fillViewport="true"` to your `ScrollView`.